# How to switch from embedded etcd to external etcd cluster

Tags: kubernetes

Is that possible to switch existing cluster with "embedded" etcd to external etcd?

Thanks

Comment: What is your K8s version and where it is located?

Comment: We use 1.16.3 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The devil's in the details, but for the most part, yes:

1. join your new external etcd members to the internal etcd cluster
2. update the `kubeadm-config` ConfigMap to indicate to future control plane members where etcd lives
3. patch the existing control plane yaml
4. remove the stacked etcd members
5. pray

### etcd

**Be Sure** you have an understanding of [this document](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/v3.4.10/Documentation/op-guide/recovery.md), and have practiced it on a sample cluster, because if things go bad, unsticking an angry etcd cluster is painful. Make etcd snapshots early and often

### kubeadm-config

```sh
kubectl -n kube-system edit configmap kubeadm-config
```

and replace the `ClusterConfiguration` `etcd:` key with something akin to

```yaml
    etcd:
      external:
        caFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
        certFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
        endpoints:
        - https://your-new-etcd-url:2379
        keyFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/apiserver-etcd-client.key
```

### existing control plane pods

This is just the materialization of the yaml described above, but after provisioning, control plane Nodes don't watch that `kubeadm-config` for changes. You may actually be happier to just rotate all the control plane nodes if you have an autoscaling system in place, but if you have "pet" control plane nodes then:

```yaml
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    # ...
    - --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
    - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/apiserver-etcd-client.key
    - --etcd-servers=https://your-new-etcd-url:2379
```

and ensure the new apiserver pod comes up a-ok

### etcd member teardown

This step depends **a great deal** on how your current stacked members are running, whether through systemd, static pods, an operator, ... whatever, but you'll for sure need to remove their membership if the existing process doesn't do that as part of stopping them

```sh
export ETCDCTL_API=3
etcdctl member list
# find the memberid of the one to remove
bye_bye_member_id=cafebabedeadbeef
etcdctl member remove $bye_bye_member_id
```

and repeat that for every embedded etcd member as you shut them down